# Using debug_traceTransaction with geth in light sync mode

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it possible to use `debug_traceTransaction` with geth in light sync mode?

I'm doing this:

```
docker run -it -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go --rpcapi debug,eth,web3,net --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --syncmode light
```

and then using `truffle debug` with a transaction in the mainnet. I get this error:

```
WARN [03-06|19:13:00.036] Served debug_traceTransaction            conn=172.17.0.1:59382 reqid=1583521980033 t=14.206µs err="the method debug_traceTransaction does not exist/is not available"
```

Notice that other `debug_*` methods do work, for example `debug_gcStats`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe so.

To make the trace possible in the first place, all the transaction data plus some extra needs to be saved on the disk. This is not done in the light sync mode to keep it light.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder if there's some way to debug transactions without syncing an archive node. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I think you *might* be able trace live transactions and then discard data, but not sure if any clients support this kind of model.